# What are the disadvantage of SQL views?

Tags: sql, view

Recently I faced an interview and I was asked the above question.

I was dumb when I think about it.

Interviewer said:

- All people are saying views have lots
- of advantages but I find no
- disadvantages, why so?

Comment: Later, I answered him that views are nothing but a complex query and can be treated as an object or table or source.

Answer (score 4):

1. when table is not there view will not work.
2. dml is not possible if that is more than one table.
3. it is also database object so it will occupy the space.
4. When table is dropped view becomes inactive.. it depends on the table objects.
5. Querying from view takes more time than directly querying from the table

Comment: Are you sure that dml is not possible if that is more than one table? Let me check it out..

Comment: For 5th point, I found relevance here: [performance degradation](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iisclzos/v9r1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.ii.federation.classic.sqlref.doc/reference/iiyfcsqlviwadvdva.html)

Comment: For 3rd point, I am disagree with you, as views are just stored statements, so it does not occupy space, except storing the statement!

Answer (score 4):

Most of the things I would say have already been covered, I would add this though.

Views are useful in many situations but making too much use of them can be a mistake because they tie your hands in terms of query structure. Often when your overall query contains several views within it (especially when views are layered), or when a view has been adapted for a slightly different purpose to what was originally intended, you find that there is a far better way of writing the query if you just expand the views and change the logic.

Answer (score 2):

Like any tool, views can be misused particularly when you're not sure how they should be used properly.

[Chris Mullins defines](http://www.craigsmullins.com/viewnw.htm) three basic view implementation rules:

- The View Usage Rule
- The Proliferation Avoidance Rule
- The View Synchronization Rule

If you don't get these things right you get code maintenance problems, performance problems, security problems, etc.

Answer (score 1):

The only disadvantage I can think of is that you may force the user to join several views to get the data in a way that is useful to them, as you now have largely static queries.

So, if the view was created one time and it is expected to never change, you may end up with a preponderance of views that creates a maze for the user to navigate through, so there should be some process to update views, to keep them useful as needs change.

Answer (score 1):

1) when a table is dropped ,view will be affected.
2) If column name is renamed then view will show exception "Invalid column name" .
3)When view is created for large table ,it occupies some memory .

Answer (score 1):

1. If you write some complex views, while querying simple data from view it will take more time.
2. It affects performance. Querying from view takes more time than directly querying from the table.
3. If view would join more than one table, you may not perform any DML
   operations.
4. Table dependence- if you change table, you need to
   updated view also.

Comment: Do you have any links/docs to support "Querying from view takes more time than directly querying from the table."?! If yes, how much of a performance difference are we talking about?

Answer (score 0):

A view permits the DBA (database administrator) to tightly control what goes in and comes out of a database.

In banking a view is often used to permanently keep track of every change made to the table. The real table typically contains additional columns that are not seen by "the view" such as:

- last-modified (when the last change was made)
- last-action (update/delete/add)
- last-actioner (person who updated the row)

So when displaying the view of the table only the latest update or add of any row is displayed. However the table still contains every existing change and row deletion.

The major downside to a view is to the user of the table (the application programmer) who cannot directly change the underlying table (for performance reasons, for example). Additionally it does create more work for the database administrator. You might also consider the extra CPU burden placed upon the server - particularly if it is utilised by many clients.

Comment: "only downside to a view is... the user... cannot directly change the underlying table" -- they can if the DBA uses an `INSTEAD OF` style trigger on the `VIEW`.